# Large websites - multiple databases or or multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm wondering how websites like youtube/facebook/stackoverflow etc. work. Do they use single database with many tables or multiple databases? If so (multiple), why? Is it faster option?

Comment: They don't use any of the options you mentioned. Also, there have been articles on how large sites scale. You could have googled them.

Comment: @N.B. StackOverflow and many websites still use relational databases.

Comment: @XMLforDummies - I never said they don't use relational databases, feel free to re-read what I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to do with performance.
Databases separate unrelated data domains and deploying items.

If two tables might be related to the same application then they should be in the same database.

One exception is when a table is reused accross many unrelated applications. Then it can have its own database and then the apps can use more than one database.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of cramming all tables into 1 database?

Comment: @Pacerier Lack of organization, large backup file sizes, deployment delay, slower administration

Comment: Not true, it depends on the organizer (db admin). I can have just 1 *folder* and organize my files better than another with more than one *folder*.

Answer (score 4):

You can find some information here: 
[Example : Youtube Architecture](http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture)
On this website, you will also see the evolution of Youtube which can be interesting for you in order to know how it works.